# How do I sort a 2D array in Python by multiple columns?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional (2D) Python array (array of arrays):

```py
arr = [[130, 175, 75, 152],
 [96, 132, 122, 112],
 [174, 218, 141, 196],
 [661, 701, 21, 683],
 [707, 746, 375, 724],
 [957, 998, 305, 980],
 [768, 806, 26, 788],
 [957, 998, 394, 974],
 [768, 806, 286, 787],
 [174, 218, 328, 194],
 [894, 933, 80, 914],
 [130, 175, 182, 152],
 [96, 132, 329, 114],
 [894, 933, 166, 913]]
```

and I want to sort it hierarchically first by column 1, then by column 2, then by column 3, like a pivot table or multiple column sort in Excel.

The result should be:

```py
[[96, 132, 122, 112],
 [96, 132, 329, 114],
 [130, 175, 75, 152],
 [130, 175, 182, 152],
 [174, 218, 141, 196],
 [174, 218, 328, 194],
 [661, 701, 21, 683],
 [707, 746, 375, 724],
 [768, 806, 26, 788],
 [768, 806, 286, 787],
 [894, 933, 80, 914],
 [894, 933, 166, 913],
 [957, 998, 305, 980],
 [957, 998, 394, 974]]
```

I used `arr.sort()` but I am not sure what goes on underneath and would like something more deterministic.

1. How do I do that numerically (not lexicographically)?
2. How would I do it on any column combination (in a general sense)?

Comment: Hi. I don't understand what it is that you dislike about `arr.sort()`. It seems like the answer to your problem is to use `arr.sort()`. The accepted answer below is uselessly complicated; just use `arr.sort()`. There is nothing "not deterministic" about `arr.sort()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Python already sorts numbers numerically. If you want lexigraphic sort, you'd need to convert numbers to strings.
2. Easiest way to sort by multiple columns is by employing the fact that Python guarantees sorts are **stable** - which means order of elements is kept in case they are tied in regards to sorting key.
   Using that, you can sort from least significant to most significant key, resulting in expected output:

```
res = sorted(
        sorted(
            sorted(
                sorted(arr, key = lambda x: x[3]),
                key = lambda x: x[2]),
            key = lambda x: x[1]),
        key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
[96, 132, 122, 112]
[96, 132, 329, 114]
[130, 175, 75, 152]
[130, 175, 182, 152]
[174, 218, 141, 196]
[174, 218, 328, 194]
[661, 701, 21, 683]
[707, 746, 375, 724]
[768, 806, 26, 788]
[768, 806, 286, 787]
[894, 933, 80, 914]
[894, 933, 166, 913]
[957, 998, 305, 980]
[957, 998, 394, 974]
```

Comment: I dislike this answer for two reasons. (1) It is uselessly complicated. `res = sorted(arr)` would produce exactly the same result; there is no need to sort four times with custom lambda keys. (2) Your last comment is false. Both `list.sort` and `sorted` sort lexicographically by default, which is why `[96, 132, 122, ...]` comes before `[96, 132, 329, ...]`.

Comment: @Stef (2) I'm not sure how that proves anything is sorted lexigraphically. Example of lexicographical vs numerical sort can be seen with `print(sorted(["96", "123"])); print(sorted([96, 123]))` - the outputs are `['123', '96']; [96, 123]`. Your example will be sorted the same regardless of if it's lexical or numerical sort.

Comment: @Stef (1) That's true for this case, but it doesn't help with anything more complex, if columns used for sorting are different order (for example (1->4->2->3)), if some should be ignored for sorting etc.

Comment: Even for something more complicated, there would be a better solution than to sort four times. You could sort once and specify a key which tells how to sort, either using a lambda or itemgetter. As for your comment about lexicographical sorting I don't understand it. If you're looking for a "proof", I suggest reading the documentation for `list.sort` and `sorted`, or read their code in the CPython implementation, or do some experiments.

Comment: @Stef I'm not saying that's best solution (as in most optimal), but I do think it's easiest to understand while still being flexible enough to allow different sorting scenarios. And yes, the lists are sorted lexicographically in regards to their elements, but the elements themselves are sorted numerically if they are numbers. Asking about numerical sorting does not make any sense if you try to apply it sorting lists of lists, therefore it was clear to my that it applied to the numbers themselves.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that there is a good reason why copious hours have been spent and numerous papers written discussing various sorting algorithms and their benefits. One could reasonably argue that the simple comparison of just two discrete values is one sorting operation. Sorting a list of only 3 elements completely necessarily requires 3 comparisons. @Stef, yes, for a simple table sort, `.sort()` may be fine, but I was also asking for the more generalized method that could be applied to a number of different sorting requirements, and I thank @matszwecja for the generalized solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Using `argsort` :**

```py
arr = np.array([[130, 175, 75, 152],
 [96, 132, 122, 112],
 [174, 218, 141, 196],
 [661, 701, 21, 683],
 [707, 746, 375, 724],
 [957, 998, 305, 980],
 [768, 806, 26, 788],
 [957, 998, 394, 974],
 [768, 806, 286, 787],
 [174, 218, 328, 194],
 [894, 933, 80, 914],
 [130, 175, 182, 152],
 [96, 132, 329, 114],
 [894, 933, 166, 913]])

sorted_arr = arr[arr[:, 0].argsort()]
print(sorted_arr)
```

outputs what you want.
Short explanation ([more details here](https://opensourceoptions.com/sort-numpy-arrays-by-columns-or-rows/)) is getting the sorted **indices** of the columns of your array using `argsort()` then use the `argsort` result as the row indices and assign the resulting array back to a, as follows.

If you want (as in your second point ?) sort it based on the second column, use `sorted_arr = arr[arr[:, 1].argsort()]` or with a set priority in your columns, look in the mentioned link you should find what you want.